# Implode variables in PHP

Tags: php, variables, implode

I'm trying to implode variables, but it's not working correctly:

```
$models = array("$model0, $model1");

$modelfinal = implode("," , $models);
```

$modelfinal only returns , ,

I'm guessing I'm way off...anybody?

Comment: Is `$models` meant to have only one element, or is that a typo?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, I'm trying to implode $model0 and $model1

Comment: Ignore my answer i was thinking of explode my bad :P

Comment: @Ken: You already have them concatenated: `"$model0, $model1"` Shouldn’t take anything more.

Comment: @Ken what is `$model0` and `$model1`, what does `var_dump($model0, $model1)` returns?

Comment: Are you trying to create an array if so you might be needing explode,which my original answer had :P But i can't tell due to the your first line of code.

Comment: Is there anything reason for wrapping $model1 and $model2 in a string ( double quote) ? $models is an array of only one element. And the double expression of "$model0, $model1" is a string interpolation (that means the actual value of $model0 and $model1 will replace them in the string.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following statement creates an array with exactly one string in it, which is comprised of the values of two (apparently) undefined variables separated with a comma:

```
$models = array("$model0, $model1");
```

The end result is the same as if you had done this:

```
$models = array(", ");
```

Now you're imploding it using a comma as the separator, which doesn't do anything since there's only one element in the array (a string with a comma and a space).

Assuming `$model0` and `$model1` are defined (which is a problem you'll need to look into first), you can get your desired result either by:

- directly using `$modelfinal = "$model0, $model1"`,
- **or** by using `$models = array($model0, $model1);` followed by the implode.

Answer (score 2):

here is your problem `"$model0, $model1"` change it to this code

```
$models = array($model0,$model1);
```

Comment: Why not `array($model0, $model1)`? Yuck.

Comment: I just copy from question, i fix it now

Comment: Not me, but I think it's because this isn't actually his problem (it's *a* problem, but he's got other problems going on)

Comment: @Prix his output was `, ,`, which obviously means there's an issue with `$model0` and `$model1` as well as this

Comment: @Dave i think he is using `array` for two element not one. is is very strange to convert a string to array , then implode that to string again !!